# Move Sheet Tab to the Far Left Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to have a small script that will re-arrange the order of the sheet tabs moving the currently selected sheet tab to the far left (the beginning) of all the tabs in a Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and No. It can be done by sweet name, but not by the current sheet you are looking at. Below is some code I wrote that moves a sweet to the first position every day.

```
function tab() { 

  var reportDate = new Date();
  var tabName = Utilities.formatDate(reportDate, 'MST', 'yyyy-MM-dd').toString(); 
  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(tab);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);

}
```

Comment: I took the last part of your code and it worked just fine.  Thanks for the help Rommel!

Comment: well guess it work, i never tried to do what you wanted. When I did this code it was meant to be time driven. Thank you are marking my answer :)

Comment: How to sort Alphabetical order or Move to end?

Answer (score 4):

```
function BacktotheFront() {
   SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know how to add code to a comment so i put it above.  The above code will move the currently active spreadsheet to the front of the line (to the left).  Thanks for the help Rommel!

Answer (score 1):

This adds two menu items in a menu called "Move Tabs" which will move the current tab to either the far left or far right.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Move Tabs')
    .addItem('Move Current Sheet To Far Left', 'moveCurrentToFarLeft')
    .addItem('Move Current Sheet To Far Right', 'moveCurrentToFarRight')
    .addToUi();
}

function moveCurrentToFarRight() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = spreadsheet.getSheets();
  spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(sheets.length);
}

function moveCurrentToFarLeft() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  spreadsheet.moveActiveSheet(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for a way to move a sheet to the far left or far right without adding a script to your sheet. I built an add-on to do so: https://workspace.google.com/marketplace/app/sheet_mover/797282136202