# How to copy a sheet to other spreadsheets and move it to the first (left) position

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a script I found to copy the active sheet to all the other spreadsheets in a folder. It works fine, but I would actually like to have **that copied sheet** be set as the first (left-most) sheet in those other spreadsheets.

I know about "moveActiveSheet" but I can't seem to get it to work correctly (I'm still new to scripting.). The usage examples I have seen seem be for the current spreadsheet. Any help would be appreciated.

Current script:

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pasteSheet = [ {name: "Paste Sheet", functionName: "copySheet"}];
  ss.addMenu("Copy to Spreadsheets", pasteSheet);
}

function copySheet() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = source.getSheets()[0];
  var sourceFile = DriveApp.getFileById(source.getId());
  var sourceFolder = sourceFile.getParents().next();
  var folderFiles = sourceFolder.getFiles();
  var thisFile; 

  while (folderFiles.hasNext()) {
    thisFile = folderFiles.next();
    if (thisFile.getName() !== sourceFile.getName()){
      var currentSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(thisFile.getId());
      sheet.copyTo(currentSS);
      currentSS.getSheets()[currentSS.getSheets().length-1].setName('THIS WAS COPIED');
    }    
  };    
}
```

Comment: Activate the sheet with a Spreadsheet method `.setActiveSheet()`

Comment: How did you tried to use `moveActiveSheet`? What examples did you found? See [ask].

Comment: Apologies, missed the edit window.  I originally tried to use `moveActiveSheet` in the loop after the `setName`. Can I use the existing variable `currentSS` to set and move the active sheet in the other workbook? How would that look? Or do I need to create my own variables?

Comment: One example I found was here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011386/move-sheet-tab-to-the-far-left-using-script) Please go easy on me. My previous coding days are far in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to activate the sheet and then move it within `currentSS` after you set the name.

```
  currentSS.getSheets()[currentSS.getSheets().length-1].setName('THIS WAS COPIED').activate();
  currentSS.moveActiveSheet(1);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Indeed it does work well and much simpler than I was imagining. Kudos.