# Specified time, move the first (date format)sheet to the last place in tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to make it possible to run the script every night at 23:00,
the sheet name's based on that day's date, e.g. today's date (2022.02.11)

the sheet: 2022.02.11
move it to the last place in the tabs?

as an example I would like to achieve this with script

now:
[image]

today after 23:00
[image]

since, it should work on android and other platforms, i think its not an option to have a sidebar or maybe a macro..

I found one like this, but it just does what you do when you click on an active sheet
moves it to left

```
function tab() {
  var reportDate = new Date();
  var tabName = Utilities.formatDate(reportDate, "GMT+", 'yyyy.MM.dd').toString(); 
  var tab = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(tabName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(tab);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(1);
}
```

it was mentioned familiar here, and this script above is also from there, I just changed the date format to mine
[Move Sheet Tab to the Far Left Using Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011386/move-sheet-tab-to-the-far-left-using-script)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to move a tab to the most right side, in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function tab() {
  var reportDate = new Date();
  var tabName = Utilities.formatDate(reportDate, "GMT+", 'yyyy.MM.dd').toString();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tab = ss.getSheetByName(tabName);
  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(tab);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().moveActiveSheet(ss.getSheets().length);
}
```

- When you want to run this script at 23:00, please install the time-driven trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

#### Reference:

- [moveActiveSheet(pos)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#moveactivesheetpos)